# PDO Prepared Insertion Statement Not Working, Returns No Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a user registration script and it all works apart from the PDO prepared statement does not insert values in to the database.
The script is not returning an error.
The MySQL user does have the privileges for the actions I am performing.

The Signup.php :

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>";

if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['p'], $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['gender'])) {

foreach ($_POST as $entry) {
    strip_tags($entry);
}

if(strlen($_POST['email']) < 1) {
    echo "<response>Please enter an email address!</response>";
    exit();
}

if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<response>Please enter a valid email address!</response>";
    exit();
}

if(strlen($_POST['p']) < 6) {
    echo "<response>Please enter a password that is longer than 6 characters!</response>";
    exit();
}

if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['username']) > 30) {
    echo "<response>Please enter a username that is between 5 and 30 characters in length!</response>";
    exit();
}

if(strlen($_POST['fname']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['lname']) < 1) {
    echo "<response>Please enter a name!</response>";
    exit();
}

if(strlen($_POST['gender']) < 1) {
    echo "<response>Please select your gender!</response>";
    exit();
}

//if(strlen($_POST['recaptcha_response_field']) < 1) {
//  echo "<response>Please answer the Captcha!</response>";
//  exit();
//}

if($_POST['gender'] === "Male") {
    $_POST['gender'] = "m";
} else {
    $_POST['gender'] = "f";
}

//$recaptcha_response = null;
//$recaptcha_error = null;

//$recaptcha_response = recaptcha_check_answer($recaptcha_private_key, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);

//if($recaptcha_response->is_valid) {

    $salt = hash("sha512", uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
    $password = $_POST['p'];
    $password = hash("sha512", $password.$salt);

    $info = array(

        "email" => $_POST['email'],
        "password" => $password,
        "salt" => $salt,
        "username" => $_POST['username'],
        "fname" => $_POST['fname'],
        "lname" => $_POST['lname'],
        "gender" => $_POST['gender']

    );

    if(register($info, $database) === true) {

        echo "<response>Registration Successfull! Please check your inbox for an activation email!</response>";

        exit();

    }

//} else {

//  echo "<response>Incorrect Captcha! Please click the reCaptcha refresh button and try again!</response>";

//  exit();

//}

} else {

echo "<response>Invalid Sign-Up Request!</response>";

exit();

}
```

The register() function :

```
function register($info, $database) {

try {

    $query = $database -> prepare("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");

    $query -> execute(

        array(

            ":email" => $info['email']

        )

    );

    $result = $query -> fetch();
    $result = $result[1];

    if(strlen($result) > 0) {

        echo "<response>Email already in use!</response>";

        exit();

    } else {

        $query = $database -> prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");

        $query -> execute(

            array(

                ":username" => $info['username']

            )

        );

        $result = $query -> fetch();
        $result = $result[1];

        if(strlen($result) > 0) {

            echo "<response>Username already in use!</response>";

            exit();

        } else {

            $query = $database -> prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE password = :password LIMIT 1");

            $query -> execute(

                array(

                    ":password" => $info['password']

                )

            );

            $result = $query -> fetch();
            $result = $result[1];

            if(strlen($result) > 0) {

                echo "<response>Password already in use!</response>";

                exit();

            } else {

                $time = time();

                /*
                * This is where it isn't working
                */

                $query = $database -> prepare("INSERT INTO members (email, password, salt, username, first_name, last_name, signup, last_login, gender) VALUES (:email, :password, :salt, :username, :fname, :lname, :signup, :last_login, :gender)");

                $query -> execute(

                    array(

                        ":email"            => $info['email'],
                        ":password"    => $info['password'],
                        ":salt"               => $info['salt'],
                        ":username"  => $info['username'],
                        ":fname"          => $info['fname'],
                        ":lname"          => $info['lname'],
                        ":signup"         => $time,
                        ":last_login"   => $time,
                        ":gender"        => $info['gender']

                    )

                ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));

                $rc = hash("sha512", uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

                $query = $database -> prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");

                $query -> execute(

                    array(

                        ":email" => $info['email']

                    )

                );

                $user_id = $query -> fetch();

                $query = $database -> prepare("INSERT INTO regcodes (user_id, reg_code) VALUES (:id, :rc)");

                $query -> execute(

                    array(

                        ":id" => $user_id['id'],
                        ":rc" => $rc

                    )

                );

                mail($info['email'], "Activate your account for Code-Cluster!", "Please click the following link to activate your account for Code-Cluster!\r\n http://www.ablp.x10.mx/code-cluster/activate.php?rc=".$rc);

                return true;

                exit();

            }

        }

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "<response>An error occured whilst creating your account! An email has been sent to tech support!</response>";

    mail("admin@codecluster.x10.mx", "Code-Cluster Sign-Up Error", "Sign-Up Error; Timestamp @ " . date() . " ; IP Address : " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " ;\r\n" . $e);

    exit();

}

}
```

This is the database structure:
[image: Database Structure]

Comment: **WHICH** prepared statement is not working? You've got at least 5 in there that I can see with a quick scan.

Comment: The 'Insert' statements. That is provided in the title. I am not sure if the 'Select' statements work as there are no entries in the database. I am trying to add to the database using the registration script.

Comment: It seems there is WAY too much code in the question than required by the problem. Please track down the certain erroneous spot and post certain code, no more 5-10 lines. Removing empty lines also would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have fixed this error but now a new error has showed up. Should I open a new question for the new error or continue using this one? The problem was that date() wasn't being given a parameter which for some reason didn't show any errors so I changed all instances of date() to time().

Answer (score 0):

It should be `:email` and not just `email` in array.

```
array(
        ":email" => $info['email']
     )
```

Similarly for all other `execute()` calls.

Comment: put in some `echo` before and after every `execute()` call. Also, instead of `exit()` in register call, use `return false` and see if the register function is being executed properly.

Comment: Changes made but still no entries in the database. This was the output:http://gyazo.com/2e295271ad88b6293c249e57e9969085

Comment: This is the top rated false answer under [pdo] tag.